# Stop blank rows from being added to multiple column ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox with six columns that I am adding to when the user selects a visit# that corresponds to the Range("A2") in my worksheet. The data adds in but it will also add blank rows every time something is added to a column. Here is what I have. I don't have any blank rows with the corresponding number so I am not sure why it is adding blanks. Check out image for my excel data.[image]

```
Private Sub cboVisitNo_Click()
    Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, i As Integer

    Worksheets("Biopsy Log").Select
    Me.lstBNum.Clear
    i = 0
    For j = 1 To Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count 
        If Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells(j) = Me.cboVisitNo.Value Then
            With Me.lstBNum
                    For k = 0 To 5
                        .AddItem
                        .List(i, k) = Range("A" & j + 1).Offset(0, k)  
                    Next            
            End With
            i = i + 1  
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Private Sub cboVisitNo_Click()
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, i As Long
    Dim c As Range

    Me.lstBNum.Clear
    i = 0
    With Worksheets("Biopsy Log")
        For Each c In .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells 
            If c.Value = Me.cboVisitNo.Value Then
                Me.lstBNum.AddItem '<< edit  ###
                For k = 0 To 5
                    Me.lstBNum.List(i, k) = c.Offset(0, k)  
                Next            
                i = i + 1  
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and the theory makes sense, but it still adds blanks. If I step through the code, the blank is being added after Me.lstBNum.List(i, k) = c.Offset(0, k) each time it loops through a column

Comment: See my edit above - I wasn't paying attention when I posted: the AddItem needs to be outside of the `k` loop

Comment: Works great. Thanks!!